# Outlined Edit Text stroke color

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-styles, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to style a TextInputLayout:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_layout_outlined_box_stroke</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/text_input_layout_outlined_box_stroke</item>
</style>
```

And that's the color selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/green_2" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/green_2" android:state_hovered="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/green_2" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/green_2" />
</selector>
```

And that's my View:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/surname">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Why this works as expected applying to the view:

```
style="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

And theme is not working:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

I'm not getting the differences between these two...

EDIT: maybe I've found this to avoid repeating for each view:

```
<item name="textInputStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a **style**:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_layout_outlined_box_stroke</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/text_input_layout_outlined_box_stroke</item>
</style>
```

and apply it to a view with:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   style="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
   ..>
```

At the same time you can define:

```
  <style name="textInputPrimaryColor" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/.....</item>
  </style>
```

and then use it with the **`android:theme`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
   android:theme="@style/textInputPrimaryColor"
   ..>
```

> **In this way you can modify the theme attributes for that view and any child views, which is useful for overriding theme color palettes in a specific portion of your interface.**

More [info here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Theme).

In this way you are overriding the `colorPrimary` attribute in the style `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox`.

For example it is the default selector used by the `boxStrokeColor`.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Using the `android:theme="@style/textInputPrimaryColor"` you can are changing the `colorPrimary` for this view without extending the style.

You can achieve the same behavior using the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute in your style:

```
  <style name="My.OutlinedBox" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.My.OutlinedBox</item>
  </style>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.My.OutlinedBox" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/......</item>
  </style>
```

and then apply it to your view:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   style="@style/My.OutlinedBox"
   ..>
```

> I want all my items with style OutlinedBox to have the box green colored"? I'd like to avoid repeating theme and style for every view...I mean a "global" style that inherit from AppTheme, which is already applied to the whole application in the manifest

Currently there isn't an attribute to define a style only for the `TextInputLayout` with an OutlinedBox style.
You can only assign a global style for all `TextInputLayout` views in your app using the **`textInputStyle`** attribute in your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   ...
   <item name="textInputStyle">@style/My.OutlinedBox</item>
</style>
```

**Note:** it requires the version `1.1.0` of the Material Components Library.

Comment: Many thanks for your time. Is there a way to say "I want all my items with style OutlinedBox to have the box green colored"? I'd like to avoid repeating theme and style for every view...I mean a "global" style that inherit from AppTheme, which is already applied to the whole application in the manifest.

Comment: @Jumpa I have updated the answer. You can merge style and theme with the `materialThemeOverlay` attribute. You can also define globally a style for all the `TextInputLayout` views.

Comment: Grazie Gabriele, saluti dalle Marche!